# When i press a button then i want to make a tabbar controller in iPhone application development.how?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I have an UIViewController with a button. Now when i will press that button then it will create an UITabbarcontroller of five baritems.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer following link- 
http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/create-uitabbarcontroller/